# Multithreading and O3 compilation in C

Tags: c, multithreading, optimization

I'm writing code that tries to detect when i signal changes from 0 to 1 as fast as possible (real time application). I have the following two functions

```
void *SensorSignalReader (void *arg)
{

  char buffer[30];
  struct timeval tv;
  time_t curtime;

  srand(time(NULL));

  while (1) {
    int t = rand() % 10 + 1; // wait up to 1 sec in 10ths
    usleep(t*100000);

    int r = rand() % N;
    signalArray[r] ^= 1;

    if (signalArray[r]) {
      changedSignal = r;
      gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
      timeStamp[r] = tv;
      curtime = tv.tv_sec;
      strftime(buffer,30,"%d-%m-%Y  %T.",localtime(&curtime));
      printf("Changed %5d at Time %s%ld\n",r,buffer,tv.tv_usec);
    }
  }
}

void *ChangeDetector (void *arg)
{
  char buffer[30];
  struct timeval tv;
  time_t curtime;
  int index;

  while (1) {

    while (changedSignal == -1) {} // issues with O3
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    index = changedSignal;
    changedSignal = -1;

    curtime = tv.tv_sec;
    if(timeStamp[index].tv_usec>tv.tv_usec){
      tv.tv_usec += 1000000;
      tv.tv_sec--;
    }
    strftime(buffer,30,"%d-%m-%Y  %T.",localtime(&curtime));
    printf("Detcted %5d at Time %s%ld after %ld.%06ld sec\n---\n",index,buffer,tv.tv_usec,
    tv.tv_sec - timeStamp[index].tv_sec,
    tv.tv_usec - timeStamp[index].tv_usec);
  }
}
```

I have 2 pthreads running at all times, one for each function.
When i compile normally (`gcc -lpthread`) This works as intended. `SensorSignalReader` changes `changedSignal` and `ChangeDetector` detects it as the while loop breaks. When I compile with the `-O3` or flag though it feels like the variable `changedSignal` never changes? The while loop in `ChangeDetector` runs forever while signals are being changed constantly. If I put a `printf("%d\n",changedSignal);` inside there, it prints -1 all the time. There is something done by O3 that I do not understand. What is it?

Comment: Does `gcc` even have a `O4` optimisation level?

Comment: You probably need to use atomic operations or locking on `changedSignal` since it's a shared resource

Comment: Show the declaration of the variable. You might have to become comfortable with `volatile` or C11 `stdatomic.h`.

Comment: @Olaf `volatile` won't make your operations atomic which might be a good idea in the OP's case.

Comment: @tangrs: That depends on the type and target. There is only one writer and one reader. If that is just a bool/int on a single CPU system, there is no problem. However, I agree if that is more of a standard PC.

Comment: @Olaf even then, using `volatile` doesn't guarantee order of operations (both on a compiler and hardware level). I'm sure there are specialised applications of using `volatile` in multithreaded environments but I suspect it's only really used in implementations of threading libraries by people who know what they're doing. As a humble developer, I would just use proper locking and atomic access functions available.

Comment: @tangrs: Ok, forget it! I just noticed OP is using not only this signal, but other data, too. Here a (binary) semaphore or event would be the better way.

Comment: @Olaf Declaration of variable is int (outside of main, global)

Comment: @tangrs I'm on Windows, using cygwin and yes I can compile with gcc -lpthread -O4

Comment: @tangrs Apperently the fact that I can compile with -O4 doesn't mean anything, I can compile with -O58392 too. It goes up to O3 you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very likely your program is experiencing undefined behaviour and you just got lucky when you didn't have optimisations switched on.

`changedSignal` appears to be a shared resource so you need to use atomic operations or some form of locking to ensure that threads won't simultaneously access it.

You can use the pthread functions for locking or `gcc`'s [builtin functions for atomic operations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).

Edit: As pointed out by Olaf, it looks like you're trying to implement a producer-consumer pattern. You might want to try implementing this by using [condition variables](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) instead of trying to reinvent it.

Comment: `changedSignal` is actually the wrong approach to implement an event/signal/flag to access other shared data. So that is not the problem, but OPs "solution" to the problem sharing other data.

Comment: It's not a solution yet, it's a transition phase "could I do that?" that got me wondering.

Comment: @tangrs I don't know If it's lucky that I got, the code I posted should eventually move out of the while. Even if both threads load simultaneously the variable `changedSignal` to a register, then the second time this happens `changedSignal` should (for sure?) have a value !=-1. I mean the second thread doesn't write anything, ever, right? And the actual value `changedSignal` does eventually change in global memory. There is a point after which `changedSignal` is no more -1 and will never be unless `ChangeDetector` breaks while.

Comment: @tangrs I should also note that I ran the posted code for 20 seconds multiple times (like 15-20) and all those times, all the signals that changed got detected (without O3/O4). I do understand that with lucky you could also mean the code is lucky and not the run attempt itself, but I'm just saying this for completeness.

Comment: @Crone Undefined behaviour also includes appearing to work correctly. I'm saying that just because it seems to work doesn't mean the code isn't invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @Crone your logic only holds if you're using proper atomic operations or locking. Otherwise, the compiler can rightfully assume your code is single threaded and re-order or completely optimise out certain pieces of code. In many cases, the hardware itself may re-order operations or you may get broken, half-correct values from memory.

Comment: @Crone for example, in your `while (changedSignal == -1)` condition, the compiler sees that you're repeatedly reading a value that can't change from what it can see. It could have optimised out the rest of the function and just emitted an infinite loop.

Comment: I would say that, in both functions, the compiler is noticing lots of reads and writes (or just writes in the first case) to `changeSignal` and is therefore loading it into a register.  There probably is code to write the register back to memory, but it will be outside of the (infinite) while loops.

Comment: @Crone: Without being `volatile`, `changedSignal` can be very well loaded into a register once for the whole loop, or the `while ( changedSignal == -1 ...` loop may be optimized to an endless lopp (actually gcc does on similar code) without any further test, as it can expext a global variable to be 0-initialized. In any way, your thread is busy-waiting, consuming all CPU and the other one will get executed by time-slicing. That is far from "as fast as possible". Better use an event or binary semaphore (I do not see much use in mutext here), so the consumer sleeps until awakened.